# PHP create date object from yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss string

Tags: php, datetime, date

I have a string in the format yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss and I want to convert it to a date object. How would I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use Datetime's [`createFromFormat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) or, if you don't want to go through building the format mask yourself, convert the string into a Unix timestamp using `strtotime()`.

Answer (score 19):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', '2010-06-03T14:29:00');
```

Comment: +1 great thank you - great as an alternative to pre-defined format `DateTime::ATOM` which is similar but also requires timezone `+00:00` e.g. `2005-08-15T15:52:01+00:00`. If you only have `2005-08-15T15:52:01` then you want to use `$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s'` ... in the answer above instead of `DateTime::ATOM` as that would cause `createFromFormat` to return boolean false for `2005-08-15T15:52:01` (based on my findings). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

Answer (score 1):

Remember that strtotime() limits you to 1970 january 1st because of the unix timestamp